# Is there a way to plot a bar chart with using a dataframe tuple index as 'x' input?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe (see below), which contains the probability that a flood occurs within ranges of rainfall magnitude (pcp, the index of this df), and  . I understand this to be a tuple index??

```
                FLd_prb
pcp         
(0.0, 1.0]      0.166667
(1.0, 2.0]      0.315789
(2.0, 3.0]      0.437500
(3.0, 4.0]      0.222222
(4.0, 5.0]      0.142857
(5.0, 7.5]      0.437500
(7.5, 10.0]     0.250000
(10.0, 12.5]    0.000000
(12.5, 15.0]    0.200000
```

I am trying to plot a matplotlib bar chart but I seem to be unable to use this index as an 'x' input. To be clearer, in the user guide I understand that to make this type of plot by:

```
plt.bar(x, height...)
```

So I want to use the tuple index as 'x' and the 'Fld_prb' and height...

Can you offer some ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You could use [matplotlib.patches.Rectangle](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html) to draw rectangles corresponding to your data.

Comment: Is your goal not achieved by simply using: `df.plot.bar(rot=0); plt.show()`?

Comment: The data above is a section of a larger dataframe which I wanted to extract from, but you make a very good point, I could have simply made a new dataframe with just that column and done as you say. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking your df's index does not consist of tuples, but non-overlapping ranges of values, which you can think of as **ordinal categories** for plotting.

Simply calling `df.plot.bar()` will do the trick:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.plot.bar(rot=0, figsize=(10, 10))
plt.show()
```

You can look at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot) for options to customize the plot.

[image]